# How to make a button glow?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I make a button glow or change color for a short period of time when pressed in Visual Basic without using sleep? Is there any button effect or something like that. Because of the program I cant afford to delay a funcion with using sleep.

Comment: What framework are you using, Winforms, WPF ?

Comment: Sleep?  No.  Timer?  Probably.

Comment: Im using winforms

Comment: Using a `Timer` doesn't delay a function. You are under some serious misconceptions. Anything you do will involve code executed on the UI thread so a `Timer` will be no different.

Comment: Yes, thank you i realize that now. I was using sleep in my timer to do it because i dont know the other way. But with sleep it doesnt work properly.